# Is it possible to unflag an answer?

Tags: support, flagging

I incorrectly flagged [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65541/why-does-hacking-in-movies-always-have-to-involve-extremely-fancy-graphical-inter/65613#65613) as being not-an-answer. Any way to take it back?

Comment: [Dismissed flags cost a decrease in flag weight](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight)

Comment: @Aditya - only if they are dismissed as "invalid".

Comment: @Chris Only way to know that is by observing decrease in flag weight right? There aren't clear markers showing this like in rep count.Like a lot of people have asked/wished.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way you can do it yourself, but I dismissed the flag for you. The best you can do is flag the answer again for moderator attention and explain that the flag is invalid. Usually, though, we'll look at the answer and dismiss the flag anyway if it doesn't apply.

In short, don't worry about it. :)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I do note that there's a pseudo-rep system attached to the flags now, and I want my flags to be high-quality AND noticed. ;-) Too bad I tripped over myself with a bad assumption in this case.

Comment: @jprete We're not drowning in flags on the worst of days, so all of them get proper attention. It's all good. :)

Comment: @jprete - just to add. Even if I don't act on the flag I will often dismiss the flag as "valid" if I can understand *why* the flag was raised.